# gnu parallel: Prefix output with hostname(s)

Tags: ubuntu, parallel-processing, gnu, gnu-parallel

Is it possible to prefix the output of gnu `parallel` when I run same command on multiple hosts?

I have 10 worker machines in a worker-pool and any one of them could've picked up the job, I want to find out which worker picked it up by `grep`ing log files on all:

```
parallel --nonall -S host1,host2,host3 grep job_id_123 /var/log/my_log.log
```

prints something like:

```
initing job_id_123
doing phase1 job_id_123
doing phase2 job_id_123
wrapping up job_id_123
```

What I want is to

```
host2: initing job_id_123
host2: doing phase1 job_id_123
host3: doing phase2 job_id_123
host1: wrapping up job_id_123
```

I know I can do this:

```
parallel --nonall -S host1,host2,host3 "hostname && grep job_id_123 /var/log/my_log.log"
```

but prefixing is what I was hoping for.

I'm using `GNU parallel 20160422` on `Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)`

Comment: Try using `parallel --tag`

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I only read the fact that `--tagstring` is ignored with `--noall` and ...

Comment: @MarkSetchell post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `--tag` option to tag each server's output when running with multiple machines. So, in the following example, I am asking the local host (an iMac) and two Raspberry Pis to print their OS name:

```
parallel --nonall --tag -S :,pi1,pi2 uname
:   Darwin
pi1 Linux
pi2 Linux
```